# Mariadb get string in binary format BE

Tags: mariadb, endianness, converters

If I am run query:

```
SELECT HEX(BINARY(CONVERT('ßÁÁÁÁÁČµ$€Łß' USING ucs2)));
```

I am get:

```
00DF00C100C100C100C100C1010C00B5002420AC014100DF
```

and I suppose that sequence is BE, because in txt file in UTF-16 BE is the same sequence.

How to get sequence in UTF-16 LE?

You ask why I want LE? Because the query on MS SQL server:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(100), N'ßÁÁÁÁÁČµ$€Łß',0)
```

return:

```
0xDF00C100C100C100C100C1000C01B5002400AC204101DF00
```

Thank

Jaroslav

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast with a little endian character set:

```
SELECT HEX(BINARY(CONVERT('ßÁÁÁÁÁČµ$€Łß' USING utf16le)));
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| HEX(BINARY(CONVERT('ßÁÁÁÁÁČµ$€Łß' USING utf16le)))             |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| DF00C100C100C100C100C1000C01B5002400AC204101DF00               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```